# How can I solve "chown: invalid user:"

Tags: 18.04, kvm-virtualization, chown

I installed Android Studio (ver 3.4). When I created AVD, it shows me a warning: `/dev/kvm device: permission denied. Troubleshoot`. I push "Troubleshoot", then it shows `grant current user access to /dev/kvm`.
I tried `sudo adduser "user"` or `sudo chown "user" /dev/kvm`, but it did not work and  return "invalid user" or some error?

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If you did this `sudo chown "user" /dev/kvm`, then it should have been this `sudo chown $USER /dev/kvm`!

Comment: Provided there is a group `kvm` (check with `getent group kvm`), simply add your current user to the `kvm` group. This group ought to exist if KVM was installed. You can also check which group owns `/dev/kvm` (it should be kvm). After you added your user to the group you need to log off and back on _or_ use `newgrp kvm` on the shell.

Answer (score -1):

Install kvm using command

```
sudo apt install qemu-kvm
```

then execute these commands

```
sudo adduser $USER kvm

sudo chown $USER /dev/kvm
```

restart system once done

Comment: Why restart the system? Why `chown` the `/dev/kvm` device _to a particular **single** user_? The only thing needed at the point the OP got stuck would be your `adduser` line which the way it stands would be better "phrased" as `sudo adduser $(whoami) kvm`, optionally followed by a `newgrp -` to have the _current_ login session recognize the new group membership.

Comment: @0xC0000022L Please feel free to edit the answer , I am not an expert with ubuntu . I just wrote the things which I did to make it work on my system .